# Given a vector field $\mathbf{H}$, find a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ and a scalar field g, such that $\mathbf{H}$ = curl(F) + ∇(g).

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let$\;\mathbf{H}(x,y,z) = x^2y\mathbf{i}+y^2z\mathbf{j}+z^2x\mathbf{k}$. Find a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ and a scalar field g, such that $\mathbf{H}$ = curl(F) + ∇(g).

I took divergence on both sides which gave me $2xy+2yz+2xz=∇^2g$. I took curl on both sides which gave me three horrible equations one of which I have written down below:

$$\frac{\partial^2f_1}{\partial y^2}-\frac{\partial^2f_2}{\partial x\partial y}-\frac{\partial^2f_3}{\partial x\partial z}+\frac{\partial^2f_1}{\partial z\partial y}=-y^2$$
where I have taken
$$\mathbf{F}=f_1\mathbf{i}+f_2\mathbf{j}+f_3\mathbf{k}$$

I tried to assign some values hoping to work out the rest but this gave me nothing. Please help.

Comment: No comment on my answer below? That's a pity. Without engagement I'm unlikely to answer a question like this again or one from you.

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a 'canonical' way to approach this problem. Here's my thinking.

---

The critical observation is that if there exists $F$ and $g$ such that $H = \nabla \times F + \nabla g$, then $$\nabla\cdot H = \nabla\cdot\nabla F + \nabla^2 g = \nabla^2g$$ as div of a curl of a vector field $F$ is zero.

Now $\nabla \cdot H = 2(xy + yz + zx)$. As $2(xy + yz + xz) = \nabla^2 g = g_{xx} + g_{yy} + g_{zz}$ it's not to hard to find one such $g$: $$g(x,y,z) = x^2yz + y^2xz + z^2xy$$
In which case $\nabla g = (2xyz + y^2z + z^2y, 2xyz + x^2z + z^2x, 2xyz + x^2y + y^2z)$.

If $H = \nabla \times F + \nabla g$ for some $F$, then

$$\begin{align*} \nabla \times F & =  H - \nabla g \\
 & =  (x^2y - y^2z - z^2y - 2xyz, \\
 &   \ \ \ \ \ \ \ y^2z - x^2z - z^2x - 2xyz, \\
 &   \ \ \ \ \ \ \ z^2x - x^2y - y^2x - 2xyz)\end{align*}$$

...which if you stare at long enough and play around, you can convince yourself there is no field $F$ which gives this result.

So better, we should find an $g$ where terms from $\nabla g$ cancels out terms from $H$ instead of adding to them. For example,

$$g(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{3} \left( x^3y + y^3z + z^3x \right)$$

We still have $\nabla^2 g = 2(xy + yz + xz)$. But also

$$\nabla g = \frac{1}{3}(3x^2y + z^3, 3y^2z + z^3,3z^2x + y^3 )$$

Thus as desired, $\nabla \times F$ is the relatively simple
$$\nabla \times F  =  H - \nabla g = -\frac{1}{3}(z^3, x^3, y^3) $$

Such an $F$ is given by $F(x,y,z) = -\frac{1}{3}(x^3z, y^3x, z^3y)$.

Whew.

Comment: Nice{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}

Answer (score 0):

Below a slightly different approach which first gives $\mathbf{F}$
and then $G$.

The problem at hand is quite similar to that of finding the vector and
scalar potentials in terms of the electric and magnetic fields in
electrodynamics. In that case there are standard solutions. But here, since $%
\mathbf{H}$ is not decaying for large $\mathbf{x}$, they do not apply. But
it seems that a suitable $\mathbf{F}$ can easily be found. Thus we have$$
\mathbf{H}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{1}^{2}x_{2} \\
x_{2}^{2}x_{3} \\
x_{3}^{2}x_{1}
\end{array}
\right) =\partial _{\mathbf{x}}\times \mathbf{F}+\partial _{\mathbf{x}}G..
$$
We can assume
$
\partial _{\mathbf{x}}\cdot \mathbf{F}=0.
$
Now

\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{\mathbf{x}}\times \mathbf{H} &=&\left(
\begin{array}{c}
-x_{2}^{2} \\
-x_{3}^{2} \\
-x_{1}^{2}
\end{array}
\right) =\partial _{\mathbf{x}}\times (\partial _{\mathbf{x}}\times \mathbf{F%
})=\mathbf{-\partial }_{\mathbf{x}}^{2}\mathbf{F}, \\
\partial _{\mathbf{x}}\cdot \mathbf{H} &\mathbf{=}%
&2(x_{1}x_{2}+x_{2}x_{3}+x_{3}x_{1})=\mathbf{-\partial }_{\mathbf{x}}^{2}G.
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus,  $\mathbf{-\partial }_{\mathbf{x}}^{2}F_{1}=-x_{2}^{2}$ and assuming $
F_{1}=F_{1}(x_{2})$ we find $F_{1}(x_{2})=a+bx_{2}+cx_{2}^{2}+dx_{2}^{3}+
\frac{1}{12}x_{2}^{4}$. Setting the coefficients $a,b,c,d$ equal to $0$, we
obtain
$$
\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{12}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{2}^{4} \\
x_{3}^{4} \\
x_{1}^{4}
\end{array}
\right) ,
$$
which is divergence-free. Now
$$
\partial _{\mathbf{x}}\times \mathbf{F}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
-\partial _{3}F_{2} \\
-\partial _{1}F_{3} \\
-\partial _{2}F_{1}
\end{array}
\right) =-\frac{1}{3}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{3}^{3} \\
x_{1}^{3} \\
x_{2}^{3}
\end{array}
\right) ,
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{H}-\partial _{\mathbf{x}}\times \mathbf{F}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{1}^{2}x_{2} \\
x_{2}^{2}x_{3} \\
x_{3}^{2}x_{1}
\end{array}
\right) +\frac{1}{3}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{3}^{3} \\
x_{1}^{3} \\
x_{2}^{3}
\end{array}
\right) =\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{1}^{2}x_{2}+\frac{1}{3}x_{3}^{3} \\
x_{2}^{2}x_{3}+\frac{1}{3}x_{1}^{3} \\
x_{3}^{2}x_{1}+\frac{1}{3}x_{2}^{3}
\end{array}
\right) =\partial _{\mathbf{x}}G.
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{1}G &=&x_{1}^{2}x_{2}+\frac{1}{3}x_{3}^{3}\Longrightarrow G=\frac{
1}{3}x_{1}^{3}x_{2}+\frac{1}{3}x_{3}^{3}x_{1}+M \\
\partial _{2}G &=&x_{2}^{2}x_{3}+\frac{1}{3}x_{1}^{3}=\frac{1}{3}
x_{1}^{3}+\partial _{2}M \\
\partial _{2}M &=&x_{2}^{2}x_{3}\Rightarrow M=\frac{1}{3}x_{2}^{3}x_{3}+N
\end{eqnarray*}
Setting $N=0$,
$$
G=\frac{1}{3}(x_{1}^{3}x_{2}+x_{3}^{3}x_{1}+x_{2}^{3}x_{3})$$